# pandas rows gets shifted after I try to sort

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe whose head looks like this:

```
Out[8]:
        Date    Value
0   2016-06-30  481100.0
1   2016-05-31  493800.0
2   2015-12-31  514000.0
3   2015-10-31  510700.0
```

I want to use the Dates column as the index and then sort the rows based on order of the Dates.

When I try to sort it based on the first column with:

```
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
```

the head then looks like this:

```
            Value
Date    
2016-06-30  481100.0
2016-05-31  493800.0
2015-12-31  514000.0
2015-10-31  510700.0
```

Not only the dataframe is not ordered based on the dates, the headers are messed up:[image]

Why does this happen and how should I correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `sort_values`:

```
In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
         Date     Value
0  2016-06-30  481100.0
1  2016-05-31  493800.0
2  2015-12-31  514000.0
3  2015-10-31  510700.0

In [4]: df = df.sort_values(by='Date')

In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
         Date     Value
3  2015-10-31  510700.0
2  2015-12-31  514000.0
1  2016-05-31  493800.0
0  2016-06-30  481100.0
```

EDIT:
Once sorted, you can set your desired column as index of the dataframe:

```
In [6]: df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

In [7]: df
Out[7]: 
               Value
Date                
2015-10-31  510700.0
2015-12-31  514000.0
2016-05-31  493800.0
2016-06-30  481100.0
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you also please provide some explanation as to: (1) why I get this output and (2) what is the proper use case for set_index? I wanted to use the Dates column as the index as well AND sort the rows based on order of the Dates

Comment: This output is just the result of sorting a column, in this case the `Date`. The `set_index` works on the index only, setting a column as index of your dataframe. Once ordered, you can set again the `Date` column as index of your dataframe.

Comment: It's not a mess, it's just how pandas shows the index column in the output.